# vb.net - custom templates issue with databinding expressions in repeater control

Tags: vb.net, templates, data-binding, custom-controls, repeater

I'm new here but I've been browsing stackoverflow for a while when looking for answers.

Here's the problem : I'm trying to implement a custom repeater with multiple conditional templates to avoid as much tests in the templates as possible

As for now my ascx code looks like that :

```
<custom:Repeater runat="server">
    <headerTemplate>...</headerTemplate>
    <templates>
    <custom:template match="[filter1]"><contents>[filter1] is true for <%# Container.DataItem.ID%></contents></custom:template>
    <custom:template match="[filter2]"><contents>[filter2] is true for <%# Container.DataItem.ID%></contents></custom:template>
    </templates>
</custom:Repeater>
```

Besides that this syntax is too verbose, the following code works

```
<custom:template match="[filter1]"><contents><%# TypeOf Container is IDataItemContainer%></contents></custom:template>
```

But this code fails

```
<custom:template match="[filter1]"><contents>[filter1] is true for <%# Container.DataItem.ID%></contents></custom:template>
```

and I get the error message: : 'DataItem' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'. 
It seems like vb tries to parse the template content at compile time instead of on databinding

Here are my vb classes

```
<ParseChildren(True, "contents")>
Public Class Template : Inherits WebControl : Implements ITemplate
    Private _match As String
    <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)>
    Public Property match() As String
        Get
            Return _match
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            'TODO compile filter as an expression
            _match = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _source As ITemplate
    <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)>
    Public Property contents() As ITemplate
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ITemplate)
            _source = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub InstantiateIn(container As System.Web.UI.Control) Implements System.Web.UI.ITemplate.InstantiateIn
        _source.InstantiateIn(container)
    End Sub
End Class

<ParseChildren(True)>
Public Class ApplyTemplate : Inherits Repeater

    _template as List(Of Template)
    <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), TemplateContainerAttribute(GetType(Template))>
    Public Overloads Property templates() As List(Of Template)
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Template))
            _templates = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**How can I add databinding expressions in my templates' content ?**

Thanks in advance.

Max.

PS: Would it be possible (and how ;)) to compact the ascx code so it would look like this :

```
<custom:Repeater runat="server">
    <headerTemplate>...</headerTemplate>
    <custom:template match="[filter1]">[filter1] is true for <%# Container.DataItem.ID%></custom:template>
    <custom:template match="[filter2]">[filter2] is true for <%# Container.DataItem.ID%></custom:template>
    ...
</custom:Repeater>
```

Comment: I have marked your question as a Favorite, as I am extremely interested in seeing a solution to this problem. Please make sure to update the question, or post an answer, when you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I had time to work on this again and thanks to this link (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21521/Creating-a-Templated-User-Control) I was able to implement my own custom repeater as I wanted to.

So now the aspx code looks like this

```
<custom:Repeater runat="server" >
    <headerTemplate>...</headerTemplate>
    <separatorTemplate on="1,9">some advertisement snippet</separatorTemplate>
    <separatorTemplate every="2"><hr/></separatorTemplate>
    <itemTemplate match="[filter1]"><source>[filter1] is true for <%# Container.DataItem.ID%></source></itemTemplate>
    <itemTemplate match="[filter2]"><source>[filter2] is true for <%# Container.DataItem.ID%></source></itemTemplate>
    ...
</custom:Repeater>
```

The inner source tag is still necessary to allow code blocks in the template if needed.
If anybody knows how to remove it and still keep the feature with Metadata attributes, please comment.

So for the vb code here are the classes skeleton

```
Public Class Repeater
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl ' I use a UserControl so i can add support any html-bound attributes like class, style, data-*... without hardcoding them in the class

    Private templates As New List(Of TemplateItem)
    <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)>
    Public WriteOnly Property itemTemplate() As TemplateItem
        Set(value As TemplateItem)
            value.Container = Me 'to bind the container to the template instead of passing the reference on instanciation
            templates.Add(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub DataBind()
        If Not IsNothing(datasource) Then 'this to avoid nested controls Databind method to be called twice
            [... iterate on dataitems]
            [... template selection on best matching filters]
                templates.instantiateFor(dataitem) ' to instanciate the template for the current item
            [... iteration done]
            MyBase.DataBind() ' to bind the newly created controls
        End If
    End Sub
    ...
End Class

'
<ParseChildren(True, "source")>
Public Class TemplateItem
    Inherits Control

    Friend Container As Repeater

    'handle as many attributes as you want here
    Private _matchExpression As String
    <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)>
    Public Property match() As String
        Get
            Return _matchExpression
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _matchExpression = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Now the simple part for parsing the inner code has a template
    'I use the standard RepeaterItem class as the template container because i don't need more features for now
    Private _source As ITemplate
    <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)>
    <TemplateContainer(GetType(RepeaterItem))>
    Public Property source() As ITemplate
        Get
            Return _source
        End Get
        Set(value As ITemplate)
            _source = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'now the part to instantiate as template for a given item
    Public Sub instantiateFor(Item As Object, Optional itemIndex As Integer = -1)
        Dim instantiator = New RepeaterItem(itemIndex, ListItemType.Item)
        instantiator.DataItem = Item
        _source.InstantiateIn(instantiator)
        Container.Controls.Add(instantiator)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Et voilà... at last !!
Hope this will help some

Comment: Of course the datasource member in the DataBind method is not a property of UserControl, I left that out for custom implementations